# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int',... I think I changed it to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

am **new** to python and learning to get my way around it,
 Am trying to create a program that calculates the time to transfer files via adb, using 3mbps as the set transfer speed, and converting all file sizes to bytes first(*1024 * 1024...). 
Here's my code, and the error it produces at the bottom.
Any code improvements are welcome

```
  class AdbCalculator:
    file_size, size_units = input("Input the file size (MB or GB):\n").split()
    float(file_size)
    str(size_units)
    size_units.capitalize()
    time = 0.0
    speed = 3 * 1024 * 1024

    def sizeCalculator(self):
        # Change size to bytes
        if self.size_units == 'MB':
            self.file_size *= (1024 * 1024)
        elif self.size_units == 'GB':
            self.file_size *= (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        else:
            print('Wrong size units! use GB or MB\n')
        return self.file_size

    def timeCalculator(self):
        # Calculating the time taken
        self.time = self.file_size / self.speed
        if self.time >= 60:
            foo = self.time / 60
            if foo <= 60:
                return 'About %s Minutes' % foo  # Time in minutes
            else:
                foo /= 60
                return 'About %s hours' % foo  # Time in Hours
        else:
            return 'About %s seconds' % self.time  # Time in seconds


foo = AdbCalculator()
print(foo.sizeCalculator())
print(foo.timeCalculator())
```

This is the output after inputting 2 MB

```
222222222222...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Documents/Programming/python/python/adb time calculator.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(foo.timeCalculator())
  File "/Users/User/Documents/Programming/python/python/adb time calculator.py", line 21, in timeCalculator
    self.time = self.file_size / self.speed
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Am using pycharm if it matters.
Thanks

Comment: You can't convert `str` to `float` like that. You should do `file_size = float(file_size)`. That's what the error says `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'` when attempts to `self.file_size / self.speed`

Comment: @Mr.E Thanks, it worked

Comment: @Mr.E you should post this as the answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float(file_size)` this line does not work.
You should assign it to itself, like: `file_size = float(file_size`)

**some improvements:**

1. `str(size_units)` has same problem. it should be like: `size_units = str(size_units)`
2. `size_units.capitalize()` has same problem too.
   it should be like `size_units = size_units.capitalize()`